# need to replace a string from file1 to file2

Tags: ksh

Hi All,

i have two files `ft2` as source and `sqll.ksh` as destination.

My need is to change the `control=raja` to `control=kartik1` and etc for all the others too.

```
kmariappan $ cat ft2.txt 
karthik1
karthik2
karthik3

kmariappan $ cat sqll.ksh 
sqlldr aja/raja123 control=raja log=ssed.log
sqlldr aja/raja123 control=raja1 log=ssed.log
sqlldr aja/raja123 control=raja2 log=ssed.log

expected output

sqlldr aja/raja123 control=karthik log=ssed.log
sqlldr aja/raja123 control=karthik1 log=ssed.log
sqlldr aja/raja123 control=karthik2 log=ssed.log
```

Comment: Is this a one time thing?  Can't you just use a text editor and do Find and Replace?

Comment: only unix commands else ksh to go with :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {name[NR]=$1; next} 
    {sub(/control=[^[:blank:]]+/, "control=" name[FNR]); print}
' ft2 sqll.ksh
```

If you're satisfied it's working, add this to the end of the command

```
> sqll.new && mv sqll.new sqll.ksh
```